# Converting/Parsing an Enumeration to a String More Generically

Tags: apex, bestpractice, design-patterns, enum

This is an extension of [an earlier question I made](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111208/assigning-an-enum-to-a-type-instance/111211#111211).

So, using the answer from the previous question I mentioned, I am able to make a generic utility that would convert/parse an Enumeration to a String.

Now the only problem I have with my solution is, I can't seem to refactor the code to my liking. It works the way I want it to, but it is a tad more on the code heavy side than I had hoped for. I was curious if there was a design pattern (or any other way to code it) to help solve this issue. I am thinking there is a creational design pattern that will help in this case. I would be easy if I had lambda expression but, Apex is not quite there yet ;).

The code I use has kind of patterns dug into it already. It uses the Strategy, Factory, and Template(ish) pattern I believe. I have the resources to find something to solve this issue (my favorite Design Pattern books), but nothing I can think of jumps out at me.

Here is the code for my utility for just one enumeration:

```
private interface EnumerationToStringHelper
{
    List<Object> ProvideEnumerationValues();
    Boolean CompareEnumerationToString(String possibleEnumeration, Object enumerationValue);
}

private class ExampleEnumToStringHelper implements EnumerationToStringHelperExampleEnum
{
    public List<Object> ProvideEnumerationValues(){ return (List<Object>)ExampleEnum.values(); }
    public Boolean CompareEnumerationToString(String possibleEnumeration, Object enumerationValue)
    { 
       return  ((ExampleEnum)enumerationValue).name().equalsIgnoreCase(possibleEnumeration);
    }
}

private static Map<Type, EnumerationToStringHelper> TypeToEnumerationMap;

private static void PopulateTypeToEnumerationMap()
{
    TypeToEnumerationMap = new Map<Type, EnumerationToStringHelper>
    {
        Type.forName('ExampleEnum') => new ExampleEnumToStringHelper()
    };
}

public static Object ConvertStringToEnumeration(Type enumerationType, String possibleEnumeration)
{
    if(possibleEnumeration == null) return null;
    if(TypeToEnumerationMap == null)
        PopulateTypeToEnumerationMap();

    EnumerationToStringHelper conversionAction = TypeToEnumerationMap.get(enumerationType);

    if(conversionAction == null)
        throw new EnumerationToStringException('The Type you enter is either a) not an enumeration or b) not a supported enumeration.');

    for(Object particalarEnumValue : conversionAction.ProvideEnumerationValues())
        if(conversionAction.CompareEnumerationToString(possibleEnumeration, particalarEnumValue))
            return particalarEnumValue;
    return null;
}


public class EnumerationToStringException extends Exception { }
```

Now in order to use the utility, it is **exactly** what I hoped for.

```
return (ExampleEnum)RT_GeneralUtilities.ConvertStringToEnumeration(Type.forName('ExampleEnum'), 'Testing');
```

It is a little long, but it beats having the entire for loop for 12 or more different `Enum` types. That is why I wanted to build the utility - essentially for better readability and test coverage purposes.

The downside with this is I have to make a helper for ***every single `Enum` type***. So it makes it kind of an eyesore maintainability-wise.

I was hoping there was a pattern I could implement to assuage that eyesore and make it appealing on both sides. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is an idea to have this support in Standard Apex. 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LfWhAAK

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**

The Winter 22 release is adding [**Enum.valueOf**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_valueOfMethod.htm&type=5&release=234) support.

```
public Enum Season {WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL}

String currentSeasonInput = 'winter';
Season currentSeason = Season.valueOf(currentSeasonInput);
```

---

(Original)

**Analysis**

Most of the work involved in scaling the below out would just be in maintaining the `enumWrappers` map. If you have varied namespacing, you may need to adjust the `getEnumeration` strategy somewhat. IMO it's a little strong to throw an exception if you can't find what you want, so I just return `null`.

**Strategy**

It might help to use a wrapper class (top-level or otherwise) something like:

```
public class EnumWrapper
{
    final Map<String, Object> values;
    public EnumWrapper(List<Object> enumValues)
    {
        values = new Map<String, Object>();
        for (Object enumValue : enumValues)
        {
            values.put(String.valueOf(enumValue).toUpperCase(), enumValue);
        }
    }
    public Object getValue(String enumeration)
    {
        return String.isBlank(enumeration) ? null :
            values.get(enumeration.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Then you could use a `Map<Type, EnumWrapper>` like:

```
public with sharing class EnumPoc
{
    public Enum Season { SPRING, SUMMER, FALL, WINTER }
    public Enum Beverage { TEA, BEER, COFFEE }
    public Enum Etc { LOREM, IPSUM }
    
    static Map<Type, EnumWrapper> enumWrappers
    {
        get
        {
            if (enumWrappers == null)
            {
                enumWrappers = new Map<Type, EnumWrapper>
                {
                    Type.forName('EnumPoc.Season') => new EnumWrapper(Season.values()),
                    Type.forName('EnumPoc.Beverage') => new EnumWrapper(Beverage.values()),
                    Type.forName('EnumPoc.Etc') => new EnumWrapper(Etc.values())
                };
            }
            return enumWrappers;
        }
        private set;
    }
    public static Object getEnumeration(String enumType, String enumValue)
    {
        EnumWrapper wrapper = enumWrappers.get(Type.forName('EnumPoc', enumType));
        return (wrapper == null) ? null : wrapper.getValue(enumValue);
    }
}
```

Debug testing:

```
system.debug(EnumPoc.getEnumeration('EnumPoc.season', 'winter')); // WINTER
system.debug(EnumPoc.getEnumeration('EnumPoc.beverage', 'beer')); // BEER
system.debug(EnumPoc.getEnumeration('EnumPoc.etc', 'bogus'));     // null
```

Comment: This is much more maintainable. I will close it once I put it in motion myself.    In my defense on throwing an `Exception`: Due to the fact that the programmer has to use a `String` parameter, I didn't want them to use a `Type` that is not supported by my utility (like them putting in `Decimal`). Now if there is an `Enum` that is found but not in the given values, a null is provided. Invalid `Type`s automatically throw an `Exception` if no valid type is found (like they put in _seson_). I could add a bit more (like what `Type`)  to the `Exception` improving readability and debugging.

Comment: @ProgrammableMedley Makes sense, it's largely a matter of preference (and possibly documentation). Any progress?

Comment: Sorry about the late accept, it was kind of bust the past few days. But I wouldn't neglect accepting an answer (especially this one), I hate it when other people do that to me, I wouldn't do that to you ;),

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. :)

Answer (score 7):

With quite a bit of magic, I've come up with a generic method that should work for any enum type (haven't tested with custom namespaces):

```java
public static Object parseEnum(string enumString, Type enumType) {
    Type cType = Type.forName(String.format('List<{0}>', new List<String>{ enumType.getName() }));
    return ((List<Object>) JSON.deserialize(String.format('["{0}"]', new List<String>{ enumString }), cType))[0];
}
```

Calling it is a bit awkward, but still better than other solutions IMO:

```java
TriggerOperation operationType = (TriggerOperation) 
     parseEnum('before_delete', TriggerOperation.class);
System.debug(operationType);  // -> BEFORE_DELETE
```

---

### Explanation

In what seems like a bug, enums are not "round-trip" serializable. IOW, the following code will fail with an error: `System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object`

```
TriggerOperation op = (TriggerOperation) JSON.Deserialize(
  JSON.serialize(TriggerOperation.BEFORE_INSERT), 
  TriggerOperation.class
);
```

However, when enums are a `class` property or in a `List` they deserialize without issue.  The Solution takes advantage of the latter.