# Passing enum value to AuraEnabled method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, enum

I have an `@AuraEnabled` method that has an enum as a parameter. How do I pass this in from a Lightning component?

Component code:

```
var action2 = component.get("c.doSomething");
action2.setParams({
    name: ??????
});
action2.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var test = response.getReturnValue();
});
$A.enqueueAction(action2);
```

Controller:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String doSomething(Person name){
    return 'Did this work?';
}

public enum Person{ADAM, BOB, CLARISSA, DAVID, ED, FELICIA}
```

I have tried several things, but either I get a javascript error, or the method returns null.

Comment: I believe you'll have to pass a string and then convert.

Comment: See also https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/111215/2995

Comment: The linked question is a workaround; the way I believe it *should* work is currently throwing a "gack" ("An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 2132073340-39340 (-2040184674)"), which makes me think that at least someone knows about it.